# Why aren't iron golems spawning in my iron farm?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've had no luck in getting iron golem to spawn in my underground iron farm.

The whole farm is right in the middle of a real village, all the villagers are now on the farm and not at the surface.

My spawning area for the golems is 16x16 and is covered at the top

The space between the doors and the wall has a direct skylight all around.

I have around 10 villagers on each side of the spawning area, and they are level with my doors. They can breed when I feed them.

I am playing the bedrock edition on switch.

Here are some pictures of it:

[image: topview]
[image: skylight]
[image: villager prison]

Comment: Are there blocks above the doors?

Comment: Not directly, but their are some about 6 blocks above the doors

Comment: Do the villagers have access to the doors?

Answer (score 1):

There have to be at least 11 villagers and 21 doors in order for it to spawn.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides of this coin either you don't have enough villagers/village is not large enough OR you just need to move your farm to the top where it would be more likely. There is the long hard way for the golem finding a cave and mining until you have enough.

Comment: The height of a village usually doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help is trapping zombies so that the villagers can see the zombies. Iron golems spawn based off villager fear (sort of), so that could increase the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

what blocks are the iron golems meant to spawn on iron golems are meant to spawn on "village blocks". ex: wood, dirt, farmland, and slabs.
Also, make sure your villagers have jobs.